# How can I obtain the -D parameters passed in to Java launch

Tags: java, properties

I am passing in certain -D environment variables as VM options to a Java server application.

I need to retrieve those variables from the application, but when I use System.getProperties() I am getting all of those, plus all of the system properties defined at the operating system level, which I am not interested in.

Is there any way to just discover the -D parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can obtain it using [RuntimeMXBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/RuntimeMXBean.html)(The management interface for the runtime system of the Java virtual machine) like this

```
RuntimeMXBean bean = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
List<String> args = bean.getInputArguments();
```

Please Note that [getInputArguments()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/RuntimeMXBean.html#getInputArguments())
Returns the input arguments passed to the Java virtual machine which does not include the arguments to the main method. This method returns an empty list if there is no input argument to the Java virtual machine.

Answer (score 1):

This is available in the `RuntimeMXBean` provided by the VM. You can get a List of command-line parameters through the `getInputArguments()` call...

```
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;

public class CmdLine {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println(ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getInputArguments());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to use a special prefix for the properties you are using, so that you can distinguish them from others: `java -Dfoo.bar=x -Dfoo.bat=y -Dfoo.baz=z  ...`, then:

```
for(Map.Entry<String,String> kv:  System.getProperties().entrySet()) {
    if(kv.getKey().starts with("foo")) {
        System.out.println("Command line property " + kv.getKey() + "=" + kv.getValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: Whoever is downvoting this, care to elaborate? Do you think this answer is inaccurate, irrelevant or not useful?

Comment: Don't you hate when people do that? But your answer is a bit of a hack, that's probably why they down voted it. Anyway, I checked it back up a notch.

Comment: Thanks :) I disagree, that it is a hack though. Prefixing property names with a "namespace" of sorts is a fairly standard practice in the industry. You don't normally name your properties "cacheSize", do you? You'd probably prefer something like `vinnygray.cache.size`, right?

Comment: That is true, but it is not always exclusive. Perhaps there are different name spaces, perhaps there are exceptions. The OP seemed to be requesting a pure solution. I had the same question, and the namespace solution would not always work for me, and I was also curious if Java provides a pure way to obtain this information. I also checked you up a notch, so back to normal!

Comment: Well, if you are looking for a way to get the JVM command line, you should ask just that (and `.getInputArguments` would be the answer). But if you are looking specifically for system properties, passed in on command line, then I think, looking at `System.getProperties()` is actually the right approach, while obtaining a command line form JMX and rescanning it is in fact a hack, with many surprises and unforeseen corner cases to be expected.